# vb.net: repaint when a variable changed

Tags: vb.net, events, repaint

I have designed a circle here:

```
Private Sub HeatmapBande_Paint(sender As Object, e As ystem.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)  Handles Me.Paint  
'draw a circle here  
End Sub
```

there is a radius(rayonZoneElectrodeEnCases) for the circle:

```
Public Property ProRayonZoneElectrodeEnCases() As Integer
    Get  
        Return rayonZoneElectrodeEnCases  
    End Get  
    Set(value As Integer)  
        rayonZoneElectrodeEnCases = value
        'reapint but how?????
    End Set  
End Property
```

what I need is: when we call the Property to change the radius like this: MyClass.ProRayonZoneElectrodeEnCases = 10, the circle will be repainted

I dont know what to do, can u help me?

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Form's paint event to perform the drawing then add `Me.Invalidate()` into the properties' set method

```
Public Property ProRayonZoneElectrodeEnCases() As Integer
Get  
    Return rayonZoneElectrodeEnCases  
End Get  
Set(value As Integer)  
    rayonZoneElectrodeEnCases = value
    Me.Invalidate()
End Set  
End Property
```

This forces the form to refresh itself.
See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx